# Cant make directory when uploading wordpress theme in MAC

Tags: wordpress, macos, directory

I have problem when I used wordpress, actually start installing, the system keep telling that i can't create directories to the spesific folder in Mac, eventhough I have changed the permission (chmod to 777) to htdocs. So I have to install it manually.
Then when I tried to upload theme to wordpress, there was message apeared

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Wordpress/wp-includes/update.php on line 329
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Wordpress/wp-includes/update.php on line 339
>   Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2016/12. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

I dont know how to solve that, because I have already change the permission to read and write (777) but that message is still coming up.

Thank you for the response.

Comment: No problem you just make all dir 644 and files 755

Comment: how to do it? I used right click and get the info, and change the permission to read and write @VasimVanzara

Comment: But it doest work that way.. :( @VasimVanzara

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: goto folder name called uploads

Comment: hueman.. But it is not about the theme, the error is the same for all theme..

Comment: Yes I know that

Answer (score 0):

Change the owner:

```
cd /<wherever>/Sites/<thesite>
sudo chown -R _www wordpress
sudo chmod -R g+w wordpress
```